# Set jQuery Daterangepicker to default to this month

Tags: date, twitter-bootstrap-3, default, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am trying to setup this daterangepicker and I want to set it to the option they have in the list for "This Month".  That way it always starts on the first of the month.

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Is there a way to pick that option by default, or do I need to set the first day and last day variables individually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `startDate` option:

> The start of the initially selected date range